# using Jquery in html display the output value in the specifed url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

I was trying to display the output values in the child page url using

`$(window.open('childpage.html').document.body).html(...)`

it open the url with empty page also if I handle the same with

`$(window.open().document.body).html(...)`

it display the content in the new window. 
how to get the output value in the page content of the url specified.

i am using the below code :

```
document.getElementById("BarChart").onclick = function(evt) {
  var cdataset = 10;
  $(window.open().document.body).html('<style> table, td, th {border: 1px solid black;}table {border-collapse: collapse;}th {text-align: left;}    </style><table> <tr> <td> Clicked Radar value :</td><td> ' + cdataset + '</td></tr></table>');

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load parts of the url with jQuery's 'load' function. According to the documentation the following would be suitable for you:

```
$("#your-container").load("childpage.html #thecontaineryouwanttoinclude");
```